# Palíndromo con mayúsculas, sin modificar palabra

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo una duda. Tengo una cadena de Strings, y quiero recorrerlo y comprobar si hay algun string (palindromo), pero me da que no es palíndromo cuando tiene mayúsculas y minúsculas.

```
def metodo(texto):

      rever = texto[::-1]
      if texto == rever:
              return True
      else:
              return False
```

Por ejemplo ['Ana',  'Malayalam','Seres'] ¿que puedo hacer para me lo realice bien? Sé que puedo hacer .lower(), pero no quiero modificar la palabra. ¿Qué puedo hacer para que la palabra no se modifique?

Comment: Los strings son inmutables, al hacer lower or upper o cualquier otra transformación, estás creando un nuevo string, con lo que el pasado como parámetro no se verá afectado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes forzar el texto a minúsculas con `lower()` y luego hacer la comprobación.

```
def metodo(texto):
    texto = texto.lower()
    rever = texto[::-1]
    if texto == rever:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: ¿pero se modifica la palabra?, es que no quiero que se modifique

Comment: Al hacer `lower()`estás creando un nuevo string. Fuera de la función la variable seguirá teniendo el mismo valor (con las mismas mayúsculas y minúsculas).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer esto:

```
def metodo(texto):
    texto2 = texto.lower()
    rever = texto[::-1]
    if texto2 == rever:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

No cambias la palabra orginial, y chequea que sea palindromo. Si luego pruebas hacerle `print()` a tu lista de palabras verás que siguen igual.